# prove that Every DPDA has an equivalent DPDA that always reads the entire input string

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata, computation-models

I am reading Michael Sipser's book [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://fuuu.be/polytech/INFOF408/Introduction-To-The-Theory-Of-Computation-Michael-Sipser.pdf) and in the section 2.4(chapter 2 and DCFLs section) there is a proof for the lemma that says "Every DPDA has an equivalent DPDA that always reads the entire input string."(lemma 2.41, page 132 in the 3rd edition of the book). I have read this proof for 4 times and still i can't fully understand it and i am looking for an easier proof or an other explanation for this proof that makes it clear for me. If anyone understands this proof please help me to understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Any part in particular? The proof has three construction steps: (1) remembering that the run of $\varepsilon$ steps has seen an accepting state (2) avoiding "hanging" a step that pops on the empty stack (3) avoiding "looping" an infinite sequence not reading input.

Comment: I would suggest working through an example (pick an example of a DPDA, and try applying the ideas in the proof to it, one sentence at a time), and ask about the first place where you get stuck; and try working through the proof (work through the proof one sentence at a time, and ask about the first sentence that you can't understand why it follows).  That would help you ask a more specific question.  I'm not sure whether providing another proof is going to be helpful, because it's hard to know whether you might find that just as challenging.

Comment: @hendrik-jan The first part of proof was confusing for me but your explanation made it completely clear for me. Thank you.